# EF6 -> EFCore ExecuteSqlCommand equivelant

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oracle11g, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

I'm working to move our model over to EF Core and I'm having trouble finding a way to call the following code:

```
InitializeTime = context.ExecuteSqlCommand<DateTime>("SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM DUAL").FirstOrDefault();
```

We use the database time to synchronize everything but from what I can find calling raw sql outside a DbSet isn't available and the return type is restricted to the `DbSet` type argument.

I was looking around and found that there are `DbQuery` objects ([Article](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/query-types)) but that seems like heavy lifting just to get the current system date time.

Has anyone else come across this and found a easier solution?

Note: this is a desktop application so the code would be running client side and the system date time isn't reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone runs into the same issue.  I ended up with the following:

**Create a new class containing a `DateTime` property**

```
public class SystemDateTime
{
    /// <summary>
    /// System datetime from the server.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

**Add a `DbSet` of type `SystemDateTime` to the Model**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Set for getting the current date time from the database.
    /// </summary>
    public DbSet<SystemDateTime> SystemDateTimes { get; set; }
```

*Note: In EFCore 3.1 it needs to be of type `DbSet` but in EFCore 2.? there is a different type devoted to this kind of set called `DbQuery`.   See the article [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#query-types-are-consolidated-with-entity-types).*

**Add the mapping to the model builder**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SystemDateTime>().HasNoKey();
modelBuilder.Entity<SystemDateTime>().Property<DateTime>(x => x.DateTime).HasColumnName(@"DateTime").HasColumnType(@"TIMESTAMP").IsRequired().ValueGeneratedNever();
```

**Use `DbSet`'s `FromSqlRaw` to query the database**

```
List<SystemDateTime> systemDateTime = context.SystemDateTimes.FromSqlRaw("SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') \"DateTime\" FROM DUAL").ToList();
```

This will return a list of one element so use `First()` or `Single` to get the value needed.

Answer (score 6):

The EFCore namesakes `context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(sql)`/`context.Database.ExecuteSqlRInterpolated(sql)` (or `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql)` prior to EFCore 3, you haven't specified what version you're working with) can only return an `int`, the number of rows affected by executing the sql statement.

`context.Query<TQuery>()` (up to EFCore 3, deprecated from EFCore 3 onwards) or a keyless entity (EFCore 3 onwards) backed by an ordinary POCO are your options as far as I am aware if you want to use EFCore to execute the query.

[Keyless Entity Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types) doco:

> Usage scenarios
>
> Some of the main usage scenarios for keyless entity types are:
>
> Serving as the return type for raw SQL queries.

In terms of the overhead, it's not really when you think in terms of the unit of work/repository pattern that EFCore implements; it essentially forces you to implement a repository rather than have ad-hoc queries around the place.